# foreach parallel computing using external packages

Tags: r, r-package, parallel.foreach

I created a package myself and try to apply it in parallel computing.
Suppose the package contains **function1** and **function2**.
My code is

```
cl = makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i=1:N,.packages='mypackage') %dopar% {
   res = function1(i)
   res
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Then there is an error, the function1 is in mypackage.

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "function1""
```

However, if I change the code by adding

```
.export = 'function1'
```

The error disappears.

Thank you to anyone who can explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `.export` as OP mentioned or specify the function as `packageName::functionName`

```
cl = makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i=1:N,.packages='mypackage') %dopar% {
   res = mypackage::function1(i)
   res
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: It's not an explanation but you mentioned ` packageName::functionName`, I guess I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Lonely_rifle the issue is that the environment for workers is different and it is not exporting the functions as we like it to be